# ColorFunction that depends on angle of line

Tags: plotting, color

I have a ListLinePlot, and I want the ColorFunction to vary as the angle, so that the color of the whole line depends on its angle from the x-axis. Here is a MWE of what I am doing:

```
test = Table[{i, 5 i}, {i, 1, 10}];
ListLinePlot[
  Table[{{-test[[i, 1]] Cos[test[[i, 2]] Degree], -test[[i, 1]] Sin[
  test[[i, 2]] Degree]}, {test[[i, 1]] Cos[test[[i, 2]] Degree], test[[i, 1]] Sin[test[[i, 2]] Degree]}}, {i, 1, 10}], 
  ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
```

As expected, this produces

[image]

How do I construct the ColorFunction so that the "minimum" and "maximum" color correspond to the angle of inclination, i.e. so that the minimum angle (5 Deg in this case) gives a blue line, and the maximum angle gives a red line?

Comment: It will be easier with `Graphics` + `Line` + some color function.

Comment: I tried that, but I could not get the ColorFunction to work. Could you provide an example, please?

Comment: I mean *color function* like `Hue` or custom `Blend` etc.

Comment: Right, I see. I tried `Hue[ArcTan[x,y]]`, and it seems to color it like I want, except only the negative half of the line is colored.

Comment: `ArcTan` runs from -π to π.  Check out `Rescale`.  E.g. `Hue[Rescale[ArcTan[x,y],{-Pi,Pi}]]` or something like that.

Comment: This is a good idea. With this, I can make the first quadrant look respectable, but now the 3rd is a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want specifically `"ThermometerColors`" then try this:

```
color = ColorData["ThermometerColors"][#] & /@ Range[0, 1, .1];
    ListLinePlot[
     Table[{{-test[[i, 1]] Cos[test[[i, 2]] Degree], -test[[i, 1]] Sin[
          test[[i, 2]] Degree]}, {test[[i, 1]] Cos[test[[i, 2]] Degree], 
        test[[i, 1]] Sin[test[[i, 2]] Degree]}}, {i, 1, 10}], 
     PlotStyle -> color]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling it would be easier with `PlotStyle`.